# Eclipse Open Any file (similar to Open Type CTRL+SHIFT+T)

Tags: eclipse

In eclipse I can find a class very quickly by clicking CTRL+SHIFT+T and start typing the name of the Class and it will automaticly list all classes matching the pattern.

Is there a similar function that would consider all files in the workspace (or even better if it could be configured to only consider certain filetypes)?

I know there is the usual search functions, but i'd like to get a list of suggestions as enter the letters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ctrl-Shift-R. Open ***R***esource

Comment: Guess i only looked at the icons, and not in menus :() will not happen again

Comment: A good way to find all the commands is to go to Windows - Settings - ... - Keys, or to type Ctrl-Shift-L, which lists every keyboard shortcut.